# Turn on computer remotely (internet) and without WOL support

Tags: networking, windows-10, wake-on-lan

I know that we can remotely (using internt) turn on the computer if the NIC card support WOL and by enabling that option on the bios.

But my card doesn't support WOL and I dont want to change it, So I'm looking for an alternative to turn on my computer when I'm out of the house. Is there any software solution? or some kind of equipement with usb adapters (not so expensive) that I can buy to resolve that issue

Comment: First of all it would be good if you provide brand/model of your computer. Second, software solution is obviously out of choices since if computer doesn't work - software won't function. Third, do you want to turn your PC on time based schedule or you'd like to turn it on over network ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible.

please note, for this to work the PC bios in question must have options for power recovery.
(i.e. what to do after power is lost. remain off, turn on etc.)

you can use a [IP network power switch.](https://www.blackbox.com/en-us/Store/Detail.aspx/Network-Power-Switch-Jr/SWI080A-R3) 
[image]

I cant vouch for any, as i have only seen other people implement them. its usually tower based servers, real servers have out of band management for this, in the form of a NIC and embedded GUI so even if the server is hard frozen, you can still shut it down / reboot.

You can find these on [Ebay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1311.R2.TR6.TRC0.A0.H1.Xip%20power.TRS0&_nkw=ip%20power%20switch&_sacat=0) averaging around $50 U.S.

Set the Bios to power on after a power outage, when you leave the house put the switch in the off position via the administrative GUI. Then when you are out on the road or at a hotel etc, when you turn the ip switch back on your computer will power up.

I would think buying a WOL NIC would be the cheaper solution.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_DRAC

Dell had a DRAC add-in card that you could probably find an equivalent for.

Its a remote management card that has its own IP and etc, but still plugs into the server.

---

If you were electrically minded you could get something like a raspberry Pi, and mount it inside your case.  Every modern computer, is started my momentarily shorting 2 wires together.  It wouldn't be terribly hard to connect a transitor between the 2 wires.

Then connect the control leg to the GPIO pin of a raspberry Pi.  Then use a python or etc script to momentarily activate the transitor.

There are probably even simplier boards out their than a full raspberry Pi.

Here's one example:
[image]

Here's the details
[image: details]

Your pin configuration maybe different, but power and reset have to be there.  You could also tap the power and hard drive LEDs as a way to verify it turned on.

Comment: Never even considered arduinos or Pi's an option for that! Nice thinking outside the box dude. +1

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but since I had the same problem I want to share a very easy solution that (nearly) anybody can use (without needing specialist knowledge about PCs, Networks or electrics)

1. Buy a cloud capable smart Plug (I use a TP-Link Tapo which costs around 10€)
2. Set it up so you can turn it on via the internet
3. Enter your PCs BIOS and change the settings concerning the PC behaviour after a Power Loss (for my Asus Mainboard the setting is called "Restore AC Power Loss" in Advanced --> APM Configuration) to "Power on"
4. Plug the PC into the Smart Plug
5. Finished. By turning the Smart Plug on via the provided App you can now turn on your PC even over the internet.