# Wake-on-LAN on MSI X570-Mainboard

Tags: networking, bios, motherboard, windows-installer, wake-on-lan

I am trying to start my computer with a MSI X570-Mainboard using the WOL-feature.

In the BIOS, I already enabled Wake-on-LAN for PCIe devices. I tried it with both the onboard ethernet controller as well as another Realtek PCIe slot controller. But it doesn't "simulate" a normal turn on of the computer.

What I expect is, that, without even one harddrive or SSD installed, the computer should start. But everywhere in the internet, the people talk about Windows Device Manager settings for the ethernet controller and the fast boot feature, which should be disabled. That doesn't make sense to me, actually.

But: It is working, when I disable the fast boot feature and configure the ethernet card and I shutdown the PC using windows. When I turn it off before BIOS POST (using power button), it can't be started using a magic packet. It really only works when I did shutdown my PC using Windows before.

This comes with a big downside: My computer needs more than 60 watts when it is "turned off" (by Windows shutdown).

What I want to archieve is: The computer should start by sending an WOL magic packet to it, without the need for any OS to be installed. Actually it should work like on is pressing the power button.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 60-watt can't be right. Where did you get that figure? Your motherboard especially a recent one should be drawing a couple watts in sleep, and a couple milliamps when turned off.

Comment: I have a master-slave-socket which has a screw to define the number of watts needed by the master to enable the slaves. The range is from 1 to 80. It turnes the slaves off when I turn the about 80% (to the max value of 80 watts). But maybe the socket it broken or it's not that exact, because its already 10 years old.

But I guess it should be at least 30 watts, so that is still enough, right? And I still don't want Windows to be involved in the simple task of starting my PC. :)

Comment: Well, there is the simple fact that these cards require drivers for WOL, and to work at all in general. Some bios's have limited support for network boots, which I'm assuming have low level drivers included for it to work. (This doesn't mean they are full featured drivers, usually just basic functionality). I'm guessing this master/slave plug isn't very accurate. If you have a clamp-on type of amp-meter you could verify the accuracy.

Comment: What happens when you set the bios to turn on after power loss? You may be able to use a network power switch to get this functionality. https://superuser.com/questions/1342554/turn-on-computer-remotely-internet-and-without-wol-support/1342670#1342670 also, you can find these a whole hell of alot cheaper than the link in that answer.

Comment: I will think about the network power switch solution. It sounds like a good way to me. But it's really sad, that it doesn't work out of the box with the network adapter. My old Intel Core i7 Mainboard from ASUS from 2012 was capable of being started by WOL using the onboard adapter. Does anybody of you know a motherboard that comes with the needed drivers? Is this dependent on the BIOS or on a specific chipset?

Comment: It surprises me that the onboard isn't working that way too. I'm certainly not saying it's the best, or even a good solution. Just figured I would mention it if you can't figure out how to get it to work the way you intend. When I have a spare minute later I'll check out the mobo manual and see if I can spot anything obvious. BTW, what's the make/model of the onboard nic? Google shows it as a Realtek RTL8111H, is that correct?

Comment: It is a RTL8168.ndi.NT (that is the separate adapter in the PCIe slot), but the onboard one should be the one you said. https://en.msi.com/Motherboard/MPG-X570-GAMING-EDGE-WIFI/Specification
Thank you for checking! :)